# How can I create lots of objects with different property values?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm programming in C# and I want to instantiate lots of new objects to my application, all of the same type, but with different values for their properties. Example:

```
Student student1 = new Student();
student1.Name = "James";
student1.Age = 19;
student1.City = "Los Angeles";

Student student2 = new Student();
student2.Name = "Karen";
student2.Age = 20;
student2.City = "San Diego";

Student student3 = new Student();
student3.Name = "Bob";
student3.Age = 20;
student3.City = "Dallas";
```

This way of coding seems really wrong to me because what if I didn't need 3, but 500 students? What would be the best way to do it then?

I tried to use a for loop for this but that doesn't work because the property values differ.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: store the values in a file, and read the file.  Use a collection type, not discrete object variables.

Comment: Use a for loop and set the object properties to random values.

Comment: Also: it would be really weird if you had to hard-code 500 objects, regardless of the way

Comment: It is really weird to hardcode data in the app.  Read [ask] and take the [tour], please

Comment: This depends on what you define *"efficient"* as and how you are wanting to do this. Generally if you want a lot of data that needs to be specific you would move that into a separate source such as a database or data files (*JSON,XML,etc...*). You would then read that data and parse it into a list of `Student` objects.

Comment: You could put it all in a XML file and write simple class to encapsulate it and then simply read the content using a XmlReader.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do anything with your objects at runtime you will probably want them in a list.

Without reading from a file or database, etc., the most concise way might be :

```
var Students = new List<Student>{
    new Student { Name = "Bob", Age = 22, City = "Denver"  },
    new Student { Name = "Sally", Age = 33, City = "Boston"  },
    new Student { Name = "Alice", Age = 12, City = "Columbus"  }
};
```

I don't know your end goal however, is this just mock data, like for a test?

Answer (score 1):

Add constructor to Student like this

```
Student (string name, int age, string city)
{
    Name = name;
    Age = age;
    City = city;
}
///
Student student1 = new Student("James", 19, "Los Angeles");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if what you mean by more efficient way to do it is just to write less code, you could instanciate them assigning the property's values at once, just like:

`Student student1 = new Student() { Name = "James", Age = 19, City = "Los Angeles"  };`

If you want not just to write less code, but to - let's say - read the data from another source (like a Json list, or a TXT file) you will have to write a loader for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what you are going to use it for. If it’s for testing, then you could use a custom built tool to create random `Student`s:

```
public class RandomStudentCreator
{
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    private readonly IList<string> cities, names;
    private readonly int minAge, maxAge;

    public RandomStudentCreator(
        IList<string> names,
        IList<string> cities,
        int minimumInckusiveAge,
        int maximumExclusiveAge)
    {
         //Argument validation here
         this.cities = cities;
         this.names = names;
         minAge = minimumInckusiveAge;
         maxAge = maximumExclusiveAge;
    }

    public Student Next()
    {
        var student = new Student();
        student.Name = names[rnd.Next(names.Count);
        student.City = cities[rnd.Next(cities.Count);
        Student.Age = rnd.Next(minAge, maxAge);
    }
}
```

If this is production code, then you should be creating students based on:

1. User input
2. Some data backend (DB, text file, etc.)

But in any case, you don’t want to create a variable for each student. You probably want a [*collection*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/commonly-used-collection-types) of students. Depending on what you want to do with them, the type of collection you need may vary, the framework gives you plenty of options:

1. Arrays: `Student[]`
2. Lists: `List<Student>`
3. Queues: `Queue<Student>`
4. Stacks: `Stack<Student>`
5. Sets: `HashSet<Student>`
6. Etc.

And last but not least, you probably want to implement a constructor in `Student` that takes a name, city and age to make instantiation a little bit more compact than what you currently have:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student(string name,
                   int age,
                   string city)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        City = city;
    }

    //...
}

var john = new Student(“John”, 19, “LA”);
```

Answer (score 0):

Programming is not about typing data. Need a lot of data? - Load them from files, databases, servers, through GUI, etc.

You can make a handy constructor, you can make factories and builders, but they are not for creating hundreds of objects in a row. Even if it is historical data, one day you will want to change them, fix something in them. Believe me, it's much easier to separate them from the code and store somewhere else, than to edit hundreds of lines of code later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `500` students I suggest extracting data to a file, database etc. `student1`..`student499` implementation looks very *ugly*: let's organize them into array: `Student[] students`. As an example, let's use the simplest csv file `Students.csv` solution in the format

```
name,age,city
```

E.g.

```
name,age,city
James,19,Los Angeles
Karen,20,San Diego
Bob,20,Dallas
```

Having the file completed you can easily read it:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;
  ...

 Student[] students = File
   .ReadLines("Students.csv")
   .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // Skip empty lines
   .Skip(1)  // Skip header
   .Select(line => line.Split(','))   
   .Select(items => new Student() {
      Name = items[0],
      Age = int.Parse(items[1]),
      City = items[2], })
   .ToArray();
```